# PHP delete row via non PK

Tags: php

I have the user select a member ID, but I want it to delete the corresponding event ID (PK) so the row is just deleted. Can you suggest a simple and effective way of doing this? This is the code I am working on FYI.

Front end.

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post">
Select member ID to <b> remove total and comment. </b>: <select name="mid">
<?php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
echo "<option value='{$row['mid']}'>{$row['mid']} </option>";
?>
</select>
<input type="submit" value=">!DELETE!<" /> 
</form>

<?php
}

else
{
$mid = $_POST['meid'];
$db1 = new dbme();
$db1->openDB();
$numofrows = $db1->delete_total($meid);//basically kill off the entire row
echo "Success. Number of rows affected:
<strong>{$numofrows}<strong>";
```

Back end method

```
function delete_total($mid, $meid) {


    $sql = "DELETE FROM memberevent WHERE mid = $mid"; // This is the bit I am head scratching, might there be a way to use mid to identify the corresponding PK (meid) to delete so the entire row is killed?
    $result = mysqli_query($this->conn, $sql);

   if ($result) {
         $numofrows = mysqli_affected_rows($this->conn);
        return $numofrows;
        }
        else
            $this->error_msg = "could not connect for some wierd reason";
                    return false ;
 }
```

P.S I am aware it cannot work in its current form.

Here's the `memberevent` table structure.

```
meid (PK auto incr INT)
mid (int)
total (varchar)
comments (varchar)
ename (varchar)
```

Comment: [**Update your question**](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/17644842/edit) with your `member` table structure.

Comment: Done, do take a gander.

Comment: Yes typo, well spotted. I have an identical method in another class file and must have pasted the different one in.

Comment: Yes. Just delete the entire row based on a non-primary key choice (mid) selection by the user using the drop down menu. As I understand the PK (meid) would need to ideally be deleted to remove the row. Sorry if this approach seems overly-complicated.

Comment: As a side note you have `name="mid"` however on your else you are trying to read `$mid = $_POST['meid'];` that does not exist on your form and then you try to use `$db1->delete_total($meid);` where `$meid` does not exist either you only have `$mid` are those a typo as well ?

Comment: The problem here about not using the PK is that you will either delete all rows where `mid` = the selected `mid` or a random amount of rows if you use `LIMIT` is that what you want ? delete all the records where mid = selected `mid` by the user ?

Comment: RE typo's * Correct, it's not supposed to be work until I decide on how I want to approach this action. If all else fails I will just have the user select the meid from the drop down menu instead, and update the table that is displayed on page load to accommodate the additional information.

Comment: Then you need the PK if u want to delete just 1 specific row or some other relationship that is unique to that row.

Comment: Yes, exactly. In Pseudo something along the lines of : user selecteds mid, presses submit. Delete the entire row.

Comment: Like I said if u want to delete 1 specific row and NOT all rows that have `mid` = selected `mid` you will need to use the `meid` like this: `DELETE FROM memberevent WHERE meid = $meid`

Comment: OK, got it. But I still need to pass mid (which the user selects) into the function. I'm not quite sure it will know to associate the mid that has been passed through to the meid so it can delete the entire row. Or am I missing something. Sorry it is very late over here.

Comment: If there is more than 1 row with the same mid value then it won't know what row you're talking about, that is why you need the PK and not the mid however if there is ONLY 1 row with that MID then it should work just fine with mid alone. But looking at your table structure it seems a member can post multiple comments so in this case mid would not work.

Comment: [Here is an example of what would happen if u delete by mid alone](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e3847/1/0)